# How to connect opc kepware server through a Java program, without the username and the password?

Tags: java, server, opc-ua

I am trying to connect opc kepware server through a Java program, I want to know what jar files can be used to connect to KepwareserverEx.V5 and what is the code without the use of password and username.

I have referenced  http://www.opcconnect.com/uakit.php, and https://github.com/digitalpetri/ua-server-sdk, but it doesn't have anything that doesn't connect without a username and a pawssword. I have a program in vb that connects to kepware using Interop.OPCAutomation.dll file and uses the code:

```
ConnectedOPCServer = New OPCAutomation.OPCServer
ConnectedOPCServer.Connect("Kepware.KEPServerEX.V5", "")
ConnectedGroup = ConnectedOPCServer.OPCGroups.Add("MPM Group")
ConnectedGroup.UpdateRate = 1000
ConnectedGroup.IsSubscribed = True
ConnectedGroup.IsActive = True
```

I want to write Java code in a similar way. Searched through the internet to see various examples, but none have the above connection without a username and password not being specified.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume that you have created an "anonymous" and "SecurityPolicy.None" endpoint on KepServerEX.

You refer to digitalpetri's **old** and **server** SDK. The new project is called "Milo". I can recommend you take a look at the Milo project's **client SDK** examples using [this link](https://github.com/eclipse/milo/tree/master/milo-examples/client-examples/src/main/java/org/eclipse/milo/examples/client). There is an application of anonymous identity and none security policy.

In terms of jar, you can either build your client-sdk (see example [here](https://github.com/eclipse/milo)) or directly download the client-sdk jar from [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22sdk-client%22).

**NB** *Milo is considered to be in incubation. That is to say, it is not mature yet. Be careful using it in production systems.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's right. The security policy is none on the KepwareServerEX. I made some permission changes on the server where Kepware exists, so that my localhost computer would be able to talk to the Kepware server host. Provided credentials for my localhost, and able to connect.